# Bootstrap collapsible side menu items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a bootstrap side menu that makes sub items collapsible.

Similar to http://jsfiddle.net/
However I want link items in the submenus and not such a complicated structure.

This is what I tried

```
 <div class="row">
      <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
           <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">More<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About US</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
             <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
            <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
         </ul>

        </div> 
  </div>
```

The dropable submenu does not push the rest of the items on the list down but rather appear on top of them. That makes it hard to navigate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would you not be better using panels and the collapse plugin to make a simple accordion? Here's an example to show what I mean. It does what I think you want.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li>
                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                                    More
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">About US</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
            <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I make it closed by default?

Comment: remove the "in" class from the "collapseOne" div and it will be collapsed by default.

Comment: I believe the latest version of bootstrap gets rid of nav-sidebar.